# Запуск exec() в фоне из-под windows

Tags: php, exec

Задача такая:

Имеется скрипт, выполняющийся следующим образом:

```
$cmd = "C:/file.exe -name:$name"; //комманда
shell_exec($cmd); //выполнение комманды
```

Запуская данный скрипт в браузере, он не должен дожидаться конца выполнения скрипта, а должен продолжать выполнение выполяя данный скрипт в фоне.

На unix системах эта проблема решается `>/dev/null &`.
Пробовал  `> nul`, всё равно выполняется не в фоне...

Заранее благодарен за Ваши ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cmd = "start C:/file.exe -name:$name"; //комманда
pclose(popen($cmd,'w')); //выполнение комманды
```

Всем спасибо. Проблема решена!